# How can you insert keyframe in pose mode for armature without it being static?

Tags: python

I am trying to make my code to key each bone is pose mode for every frame from start to finish, while still retaining the animation. The code looks like this

```
for bone in bpy.data.objects[context.active_object.name].data.bones:
            bone.select = True
            for f in range(scene.frame_start, scene.frame_end+1):
                bpy.context.selected_objects[0].pose.bones[bonecount].keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=f)
```

While this code does insert key to every frame, the armature applied with this code does not move even if there were animations prior to it. How can I key every frame of the animation while retaining the animation that were already applied to it?

Comment: The problem with that code is that you've done nothing to cause the armature's pose to change.  You need to iterate through `current_frame` and apply the existing animation at that frame and _then_ update your keyframes.  But if you have an animation that's working with Blender generated in-between frames, why do you want to convert it to one with every pose keyframed?

Comment: @MartyFouts I am trying to key every frame then delete every second frame and after which I am trying to make the interpolation type constant in order to achieve the looks of the 'on twos' animation style of the 2D. I haven't been able to find other ways to do it apart from manually doing so. So far I only have the location data but I am planning to also add the rotation and the scale variables.

Comment: The code works now thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved by putting `bpy.context.scene.frame_set(f)` before inserting the keyframe.